# java8 error can not find symbol when I use comparetoIgnoreCase and Upper/UnderCase

Tags: java, string

I am trying to compare string_1 to string_2 to see if it is equal to each other, and I am trying to make an individual string be completely capitalized or under-cased.

```js
import java.util.Scanner;
public class StringMethods
   {
   public static void main (String [] args)
      {
      Scanner s=new Scanner (System.in);
      String string_1= s.next();
      String string_2= s.next();
      System.out.println ("a) Determine the length of string_1: " +string_1.length()+ "/t b) Determine the length of string_2: " +string_2.length()+"/tc) Concatenate both strings: " +string_1.concat(string_2)+"/td) Check if the two strings have same set of characters with regard to case: ");
      if (string_1.equaltoIgnoreCase(string_2))
         {
         System.out.print ("equal.");
         }
      if ((string_1.comparetoIgnoreCase(string_2)>0)||(string_1.comparetoIgnoreCase(string_2)<0))
         {
         System.out.print ("They are not equal.");
         }
      System.out.println ("e) Convert string_1 to upper case: " +string_1.toUpperCase()+"/tf) Convert string_2 to lower case: " +string_2.toUnderCase()+"/tg) Extract a valid sub-string of multiple characters from string_1: " +string_1.substring(0,string_1.length));
      }}
```

Comment: They are exact match to ~> `compareToIgnoreCase` and `equalsIgnoreCase`

Comment: `equaltoIgnoreCase` should be `equalsIgnoreCase`. --- `comparetoIgnoreCase` should be `compareToIgnoreCase`. --- `toUnderCase` should be `toLowerCase`. --- `length` should be `length()`. --- **Use an IDE** to help with stupid things like this. Or **read the documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of spelling and punctuation errors throughout your code. I would highly suggest  using an IDE like IntelliJ to prevent this. I went ahead and fixed the typo's, but it looks like you will need to do some work as far as the way the program is currently running. For instance, the program is asking for input before the user even knows WHAT to input.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String string_1 = s.next();
        String string_2 = s.next();
        System.out.println("a) Determine the length of string_1: " + 
string_1.length() + "/t b) Determine the length of " +
            "string_2: " + string_2.length() + "/tc) Concatenate both 
strings: " + string_1.concat(string_2) + "/td) " +
            "Check if the two strings have same set of characters 
with regard to case: ");
    if (string_1.equalsIgnoreCase(string_2)) {
        System.out.print("equal.");`enter code here`
    }
    if ((string_1.compareToIgnoreCase(string_2) > 0) || 
(string_1.compareToIgnoreCase(string_2) < 0)) {
        System.out.print("They are not equal.");
    }
        System.out.println("e) Convert string_1 to upper case: " + 
string_1.toUpperCase() + "/tf) Convert string_2 to " +
            "lower case: " + string_2.toLowerCase() + "/tg) Extract a 
valid sub-string of multiple characters from string_1: " +
            string_1.substring(0, string_1.length()));
    }
}
```

Comment: The `toUnderCase` should be replaced with `toLowerCase`, not `toUpperCase`. Read the leading text in the `println`.

Comment: Thank you. I have fixed it.

Comment: Thanks Andreas. I am in cs1301 and my college teacher does not help the students at all. I had to go by what I have in the slides, and it made me stuck.

Comment: Also thanks for your help Ben. I realized I needed to curve my /t the other way around to make it \t.

Comment: Hey man I understand. I took Intro to Java and Java Programming last semester and now I am in Adv. Java this semester. Five months ago I didn't know anything about Java really. It gets easier!